# The "integrate" function in R gives erroneous results

Tags: r, integrate

I would like to integrate the function M2_11 (as follows) over x, for fixed `theta = c(2,0.8)`, `c = 1.1`, `a=c(1,1)`, and `A = matrix(c(1/0.8,0.03,0.03,2/0.8),nrow=2,ncol=2)`.

```
M2_11 = function(x, theta, c, a, A){
return((score1(x,theta)-a[1])^2* (weight(x, theta, c, a, A))^2 * f(x, theta))
}
```

The integrate function of R gives the following results

```
theta = c(2,0.8)
c = 1.1
a=c(1,1)
A = matrix(c(1/0.8,0.03,0.03,2/0.8),nrow=2,ncol=2)
integrate(M2_11, lower = 1e-100, upper = 10 ,subdivisions = 10000, theta,c,a,A)
```

> 0.0006459957 with absolute error < 4.5e-05

Doing the integration another way gives the same result

```
fM2_11 = function(x){M2_11(x,theta,c,a,A)}
integrate(fM2_11, lower = 1e-100, upper = 10,subdivisions = 10000)
```

> 0.0006459957 with absolute error < 4.5e-05

The result that the integrate function gives, however, is clearly wrong:

```
x = seq(1e-100,10,by=0.001)
integrand = sapply(x,fM2_11)
```

[image]

The area under the curve is clearly greater than 0.00066

I also check the result using a loop

```
loop_result = rep(NA,length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  loop_result[i] = M2_11(x[i],theta,c,a,A)  
}
table(integrand==loop_result)
```

TRUE

10001

What is going on?

Comment: Why `integrand = sapply(x,fM2_11)` instead of just `fM2_11(x)`? I didn't dig through the code, but I guess that `fM2_11` might be not vectorized, while `integrate` require it to be. Read `?integrate`.

Comment: Thank you Nicola! I owe you one!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Nicola. The problem is solved.

```
integrate(Vectorize(fM2_11), lower = 1e-100, upper = 10 ,subdivisions = 10000)
```

> 0.1588699 with absolute error < 1.7e-07

```
sum(integrand)*0.001
```

> 0.1588705

Never expect answer to be so simple!

Comment: Just FYI, `Vectorize()` is pretty much just a wrapper for `mapply()`. In case of single argument, single result function it would be equivalent to `sapply()`